# How to Extract Part of String in Pig

Tags: string, apache-pig

I have dates that look like the following

```
3/30/2018
```

I would like to parse out the month(3) for later grouping. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to extract the months:

```
GENERATE SUBSTRING(date,0,2)--this will create a new var with the first two chars
```

Then, in case you have an extra '/' you can use the replace function like so:

```
REPLACE(MONTH,'/','')
```